# Conditional mutual information with multiple variables

Tags: python, statistics, information-theory

I am studying d-separation, and I need a library from Python able to compute I(X;Y|Z1,Z2,...,Zn),i.e., the mutual information of X and Y given the variables Z1 to Zn. I tried the package `pyitlib`, and it works fine when I use a single variable for Z, but in the code bellow:

```
import numpy as np
from pyitlib import discrete_random_variable as drv
import warnings 
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

X = np.random.random_integers(0,10,10000)

Y = np.random.random_integers(0,10,10000)

Z = X+Y
Z1 = X-Y

Z = [Z,Z1]

Z = np.array(Z).T
print(drv.information_mutual_conditional(X, Y, Z))
```

I get the error

`ValueError: dimensions of args X, Y, Z do not match`

I am aware of `fcit`, but the lack of documentation let me insecure about using it to my project. Is there any other library in which I can perform this calculation?

Comment: Your Z variable ends up being two dimensional, where X and Y are one dimentional.  This is in violation of the requirements of the function.  https://pafoster.github.io/pyitlib/index.html?highlight=drv#discrete_random_variable.information_mutual_conditional

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I know that this is the problem. I would like to know if there is an implementation which allows me to perform the computation even if Z is multidimensional.

Comment: sorry I have no idea what you're actually doing here, so I won't be much help there.

Comment: @donut The computed MI is going to depend strongly on an assumed model for the relations among X, Y, and Z1, ..., Zn. Various methods will pretend to be model-free but there isn't any such thing in reality, and as you start looking at increasing numbers of variables beyond just X and Y, the model will make more and more of a difference. One way to look at this is that the joint probability of X and Y dependent on the Z's, i.e. P(X, Y | X, Z1, ... Zn), is equal to P(Y | X, Z1, ..., Zn) P(X | Z1, ..., Zn). The second is a model for X dependent on the Z's, and the first is a model for Y ...

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am using this computation in pc-algorithm for causal networks. These algorithms usually assume gaussian independence tests, which I am trying not to use in favour of a more generic approach. I was not aware of this problem involving different models, could you please inform some papers so I could check? I don't even know what to search for.

Comment: ... dependent on the Z's plus X. When X and Y are independent given the Z's, then including X in the model for Y doesn't change the result. (This is essentially the same problem as backward variable selection, i.e. start with a lot of variables and see what changes if you remove one). I'm sure this problem about estimating MI has been covered many times, but one reference I know of is in Section 8.1.1 of my dissertation. See: http://riso.sourceforge.net for a link to my dissertation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the sources, I will read them. I have one last question. Can I determine if X and Y are independent given (Z1,..., Zn)? This was what I would like to know, actually, and mutual information was just a tool. Maybe it is too complicated to use mi in my case, do you know if determining conditional independence would be easier?

Comment: Is there another terminology for this scenario; when we want to calculate the conditional Mutual information having muliple Z's

Comment: "determine if X and Y are independent given (Z1,..., Zn)?"  Maybe regress X on the Zs, regress Y on the Zs, and then test if the X-residual and Y-residual are correlated?