# Finding if X and Y are independent given a list of variables Z = [Z1,...,Zn]

Tags: python, statistics, bayesian-networks, causality

I am running the pc-algorithm for causal networks. In this algorithm, I need to verify if two arrays X and Y are independent given a set of arrays Z1,..., Zn. In papers, it is usually assumed gaussian independence tests, which I am trying not to use in favour of a more generic approach.
I tried to use mutual information, but as can be seen in my discussion yesterday ([Conditional mutual information with multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62649132/conditional-mutual-information-with-multiple-variables?noredirect=1#comment110792119_62649132)), mutual information doesn't seem to be a good approach. I tried to use `fcit` package.

```
import numpy as np
from fcit import fcit


X = np.random.random_integers(0,10,10000)

Y = np.random.random_integers(0,10,10000)


Z = X+Y
Z1 = X-Y

Z = [Z,Z1]
Z = np.array(Z).T
X = X.reshape((10000,1))
Y = Y.reshape((10000,1))

pval_d = fcit.test(X, Y)
pval_i = fcit.test(X, Y, Z)
```

But for the `pval_i` I get `nan` and the following warnings:

```
C:\Users\Usuario\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:903: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
  return (a < x) & (x < b)
C:\Users\Usuario\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:903: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
  return (a < x) & (x < b)
C:\Users\Usuario\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:1912: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less_equal
  cond2 = cond0 & (x <= _a)
```

Which I assume it appears due the difference in dimensions of Z and X and Y, since in the case all have the same dimension (10000,1), it computes correctly the independence test. So my question is: how can I compute if X and Y are independent given Z1,...,Zn?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a dimension error - seems to me like this is `fcit` dividing by zero or doing something fishy inside which results in NaN values being calculated.

I don't know enough about the statistical test you're using to know what mathematical reason causes NaN values, but that's my intuition.

I would start with debugging the warning and see what calculation results in this. https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html is useful to make python stop on warnings as well as on errors.

Comment: I agree with you that the problem is a division by 0. However, this only happens when I try to run the cases in which Z has different dimensions than X and Y. This fact makes me suspect about the ability of ```fcit``` to return a correct value, even if I debug this error. That's why I would like to try another approach.

Comment: You can also look at `https://numpy.org/doc/1.19/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html?highlight=seterr#numpy.seterr`, maybe it can help to debug exactly where the NaNs are made

Answer (score -1):

The fact whether two variables (arrays) are dependent or independent is determined based on the two variables at hand, not on other variables. What do you mean by:

> if two arrays X and Y are independent given a set of arrays Z1,..., Zn

Comment: This is not necessarily true, two random variables may be independent, but become dependent given another variable. Take for example the network A -> C < - B. C is called a Collider, and it is true that A and B are independent, but A and B are dependent given C. You can easily verify this calculating the conditional mutual entropy if you want.